# Intellij IDEA custom dart format. How to make dot operator on the same line

Tags: dart, intellij-idea, format, appcode

I am trying to configure dart to let the operator . appear on the same line.
I am not having any success on configuring it to do that.
It currently looks like this

[image]

I would like `colors.removeLast()` and `colors.length` to be each on one line.
So it should be like

```
do
{
  colors.removeLast();
}
while(colors.length > 0);
```

Any suggestions on how I can make that happen ? Which settings do i need to change ?

Comment: Take a look at the "coding style" section of intellij's settings. Every setting is pretty well-documented on jetbrains forum/docs.

Comment: I have completely exhausted the options in Wrapping and Braces tab for code style >> dart. None of those options are helping. If you know of any option would love to know.

Answer (score 0):

Increase line length. The function call is being placed on the new line as the line cannot be longer than 20 (or so) symbols. Increasing this value will prevent IntelliJ IDEA to find ways to fit the text.
See the difference:
[image: dart code style]